# CANopen PDO sample code for LPC11Cxx

Tags: pdo, sample, lpc, canopen

I tested and understood SDO rx and tx with the LPC11Cxx demo. But this demo stack has only SDO functions and a driver [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). I want to implement PDO for the same. What would be some sample code or implementation steps or functions?

I want to send 68 (ADC data) bytes of data from a slave node to the master node at regular intervals. How can I do that?

For the above task, is SDO better than PDO? How many PDOs do I need to send 64 bytes of data? How can I set PDO mapping and parameters? What is the difference between a master node and a slave node? How do I differentiate from code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your example, but if you can send an SDO over the CAN bus, the you should be able to use the PDO, albeit more complicated.

The general steps are:
1. Define your PDO. You are creating a mapping between a PDO and one or more data objects in your node.  For example, on my system, I created a Transmit PDO that sets the motor position and velocity (two objects) that responds with another PDO (a receive PDO) that contains motor current, position and status.  This is the definition of the PDO.

2. To use your PDO, send out a PDO message with the COBid you defined in step 1.  Fore me, I send PDO 0x201 with the position and velocity.  The node will receive this and set the values you give to the object mapping you define.  Note the node does NOT act on the data yet.
3. After you've sent as many PDO's you need (for example, I send PDO for position/velocity to 7 nodes on a bus to control 7 motors), you then send a SYNC. This causes the nodes to act on the PDO data you've sent - ie move the motors.
4. Each node will respond with a transmit PDO to send back whatever you define.  My nodes send position, status, and current.

Repeat as needed.

Google "CANOpen momento dupin" for some example in the document.  You'll have to read the doc on  your nodes to understand how they are defined, or the chapter in the embedded canopen book.  I have some old code you can look at the was provided to me from a vendor. That might be a good source as well.  Nodes don't have to support PDO mapping but I think most do.